# jQuery issue with $(this).toggleClass and Multiple btns and elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-instances, toggleclass

I am having trouble figuring this out. I have come up with jQuery that I can use multiple buttons to open a corresponding div using css transitions. I don't want to use text but the + and - to illustrate that the item is open and closed.

I want the + to change to - when you click on other + items. I also want the + on the current item to toggleClass or change from + to - and back to +

I am hoping that a fresh set of eyes with more JS skill can set me straight.

So here is my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<style> 

.btn {display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; width:20px; margin:1%; padding:.3em .8em; border-radius:20px; color:#fff; text-align:center; background-color:#FFB50B;}

.btn:hover {cursor:pointer; opacity:.7; color:#000;}

.btn-pnl:before {content:"+"; font-weight:600px;}

.btn-pnl-viz:before {content:"-";}

.hidden {visibility:hidden;}

.panels-wrap {width:870px; height:auto; margin:0 auto; padding:0;}

.panel {width:98%; height:0px; float:left; margin:0 1%; padding:0; opacity:0; visibility:hidden; background:#f60; color:rgba(0,0,0,0);

-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;

}

.panel-trn {width:100%; height:100px; visibility:visible; opacity:1; color:rgba(0,0,0,1); background:#0F0}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding selector from data-toggle
$(selector).toggleClass('panel-trn').siblings().removeClass("panel-trn");           
});

$('a').click(function() {
$("a").removeClass("btn-pnl-viz");

//Tried this and no luck > $(this).toggleClass('btn-pnl-viz');

if ($(this).hasClass("btn-pnl-viz")){
$(this).removeClass("btn-pnl-viz");
}else{
$(this).toggleClass("btn-pnl-viz");
};         
}); 
});


</script>

<div>
<div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div1" class="btn btn-pnl"></a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div2" class="btn btn-pnl"></a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div3" class="btn btn-pnl"></a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="panel">div 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="panel">div 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="panel">div 3</div>

</div>

<div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div4" class="btn btn-pnl"></a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div5" class="btn btn-pnl"></a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div6" class="btn btn-pnl"></a>
</div>

<div id="div4" class="panel">div 1</div>
<div id="div5" class="panel">div 2</div>
<div id="div6" class="panel">div 3</div>
```

I can get everything to work except I cant get the button to toggle the + and - if I click the same button twice. I also cannot get the existing active to close when clicking on another button out side of the container div.

Total Newb question I know but, if someone could help I would greatly appreciate it... many hours on this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the code of $("a").click();

with following i testesed its working fine

```
$('a').click(function() {


    ($("a").not($(this))).removeClass("btn-pnl-viz");
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-pnl-viz");

});
```

Reply if any problem with the code
Thanks

Comment: Thank you! That does work and it led me to answer my other question! I also wanted to close the other open panels on the page so that there was only one open at any given time, and, it toggled! The problem I was having was that the .siblings() wasn't working on the panels outside of the div. So I modified your working example for the other toggleClass...

($("div").not(selector)).removeClass("panel-trn");

and that worked like a charm!

Thanks again!